# AChartEngine Bar Chart Margin Issues

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, margins

to begin, here is a link to what my application currently looks like: [image: ds]

Of the two charts shown, I want to get rid of the margin on the left for the bar chart.  Any ideas?

Below are my renderer settings.  I've searched and wasn't able to find people with a similar issue.  It seems like it should be simple...

```
private void drawBarChart(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset) {
    int marginT = 10;
    int marginL = 5;
    int marginB = 10;
    int marginR = 5;
    int[] margins = {marginT, marginL, marginB, marginR};

    ...

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(2).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setMargins(margins);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(maxYVal);
    renderer.setYLabels(0);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(2);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false,false);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(-0.5);
    renderer.setShowAxes(false);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);

    ...

    display chart in view
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sneaky.

I was playing around with the margins because I decided to use my own TextViews as titles since they render much nicer than the titles rendered by AChartEngine.  According to the documentation, it states the the margins work as follows:

```
margins - an array containing the margin size values, in this order: top, left, bottom, right
```

which is why I set my margins variable as follows:

```
int[] margins = {marginT, marginL, marginB, marginR};
```

It turns out that for a horizontal bar chart, marginB controls the left margin and marginT controls the right margin.  In other words, all the margins have to be rotated clockwise to work as intended.  (i.e. to change the right margin, you change the margin for 'top'; to change the top margin, you change the margin for 'left'; etc.)